# Search using regular expression in a browser?

Tags: regex, search, browser

is there a way to search within a browser (with any of them) using regular expression? Let's say I want to search for either "python" or "php" I don't want to have to do this twice. Ideally, this could be done within the regular GUI, but if not, using add-ons/plug-ins with Web Inspector (webkit) or Firebug is fine too. Thanks!

Comment: using the browser's built-in search? (CTRL+F, etc.)

Comment: @jnpcl as far as I know, no browser's built-in search allows regexp search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within a single page? Install the ["highlight regexp" bookmarklet](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/pagedata.html) for JavaScript regexps.